# Matching function in matlab to do a Pandas resample

Tags: matlab, reshape

When you want to resample data in python according to the time stamp the pandas resample function it is easily used. For example from a dataframe1 with the time stamp in seconds to another one resampled to 10 minutes average.

```
df1_10m=df1.resample('10T', how='mean')
```

Now I need to do the same in matlab, but I do not find a clear way to do it.

The function resample seems to be something else.

I tried with reshape but I get errors.

```
function[Data_10mean]=resamp(table)
table.ts=datestr(table.ts); % format the time stamp
TableArray=table2array(table)
j=1;
for i=1:13
    temp=TableArray(:,i);
    table_r=reshape(temp,600,[]); 
    table_rmean=mean(table_r,'omitnan');
    Size=size(table_rmean);
    temp_index=Size(2);
    Data_temp=reshape(table_rmean,temp_index,1);
    Data_10mean(:,j)=Data_temp(:,1);
    j=j+1; %counter for the columns of each iteration
end  

end

Error using reshape
Product of known dimensions, 600, not divisible into total number of elements, 13526.
```

If I ask for help is because I really need it. I am familiar with python and not much with matlab. Something so simple in python seems not to have a specific function in matlab.

Comment: Reshaping an array in MATLAB simply changes the dimensions of the array, but the **total number of elements** upon reshaping should NOT change.  What you are doing with `reshape` is that you are expecting that the output result should have 600 rows, but MATLAB is complaining because doing so means that the total number of columns that results when reshaping with 600 rows is not possible. `tl;dr`: You have 13526 elements in a vector and are trying to create a matrix with 600 rows.  Is that possible?

Comment: ok. Any alternative solution?? @rayryeng

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function [retime](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/timetable.retime.html) in matlab :

> retime: Resample or aggregate data in timetable, and resolve duplicate or irregular times

```
TT2 = retime(TT1,newTimeStep,method)
```

It has a `mean` function in method.